# joint probability and conditional probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

The number of workplace injuries, $N$, occuring in a factory on any given day is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ . The parameter $\lambda$ is a random variable that is determined by the level of activity in the factory, and is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,3]$. Calculate $Var[N]$.

The answer 2.25 and i saw the answer used the relationship of $Var[N]=E(Var(N|\lambda)+Var(E[N|\lambda])$ but I'm not sure why this conditional probability is needed to be applied. Hope someone can explain how I should approach this problem thanks!

Comment: You are given the _conditional_ probability that $N=n$ _given_ that $\lambda$ has a specific real number value in $[0,3]$, and not the _unconditional_ probability that $N=n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the distribution of $N$ is given as Poison with parameters $\lambda$, but $\lambda$ is itself a random variable with (continuous) uniform distribution over interval $[0;3]$.  So what you are actually given is the **conditional** distribution of $N\mid\lambda$, not the unconditional distribution $N$.

So you must use the [Law of Total Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)

$$\begin{align}
(N\mid \lambda) &\sim \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)
\\[2ex]
\Lambda &\sim \mathcal{U}[0;3]
\\[2ex]
\mathsf{Var}(N) & = \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf{Var}\big(N\mid \lambda\big)\Big)+\mathsf {Var}\Big(\mathsf E\big(N\mid \lambda\big)\Big)
\end{align}$$

The first thing you must do is evaluate the variance and expectation of a Poisson Distribution: $\mathsf {Var}(N\mid\lambda)$ and $\mathsf E(N\mid \lambda)$ (which will be in terms of the r.v. $\lambda$).  The next thing will to evaluate the variance and expectation of those results.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the tower rule:

$$\mathbb E[N] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[N|\lambda]].$$

So $$
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{Var}(N) &= \mathbb E[N^2] - \mathbb E[N]^2\\
&= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[N^2|\lambda]] - \mathbb E[\mathbb E[N|\lambda]]^2\\
\end{align*}
$$
By linearity of conditional expectation, this is equal to
$$
\mathbb E[\mathrm{Var}(N)|\lambda] + \mathbb E[\mathbb E[N|\lambda]^2] - \mathbb E[\mathbb E[N|\lambda]]^2,
$$
which is simply
$$\mathbb E[\mathrm{Var}(N)|\lambda] + \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb E[N|\lambda]). $$